# Error while installing virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I've tried everything and I can't install virtualenvwrapper.

I have installed python 2.7.6 and virtualenv.

I'm using MacOSX Mavericks.

When I try to install with `pip install virtualenvwrapper` or `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper` came with this error.

```
Downloading virtualenvwrapper-4.2.tar.gz (125kB): 125kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package virtualenvwrapper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/hl/n7326xr91ls3z8c3s08_dv4r0000gn/T/pip_build_rafagomes/virtualenvwrapper/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    pbr=True,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 564, in resolve
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 802, in best_match
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 814, in obtain
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 593, in easy_install
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in install_item
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 809, in install_eggs
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1015, in build_and_install
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1000, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 50, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 100, in run
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 52, in <lambda>
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/hl/n7326xr91ls3z8c3s08_dv4r0000gn/T/easy_install-fh8Xd1/pbr-0.5.23/pbr/util.py", line 259, in cfg_to_args
  File "/var/folders/hl/n7326xr91ls3z8c3s08_dv4r0000gn/T/easy_install-fh8Xd1/pbr-0.5.23/pbr/util.py", line 480, in wrap_commands
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 772, in get_command_list
    klass = self.get_command_class(cmd)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 366, in get_command_class
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 815, in get_command_class
    __import__ (module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/check.py", line 13, in <module>
    from docutils.utils import Reporter
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils/utils/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from docutils.io import FileOutput
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils/io.py", line 18, in <module>
    from docutils.utils.error_reporting import locale_encoding, ErrorString, ErrorOutput
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils/utils/error_reporting.py", line 47, in <module>
    locale_encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 511, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 443, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
File "/private/var/folders/hl/n7326xr91ls3z8c3s08_dv4r0000gn/T/pip_build_rafagomes/virtualenvwrapper/setup.py", line 7, in <module>

pbr=True,

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup

_setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 564, in resolve

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 802, in best_match

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 814, in obtain

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 593, in easy_install

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in install_item

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 809, in install_eggs

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1015, in build_and_install

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1000, in run_setup

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 50, in run_setup

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 100, in run

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 52, in <lambda>

File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>

File "/var/folders/hl/n7326xr91ls3z8c3s08_dv4r0000gn/T/easy_install-fh8Xd1/pbr-0.5.23/pbr/util.py", line 259, in cfg_to_args

File "/var/folders/hl/n7326xr91ls3z8c3s08_dv4r0000gn/T/easy_install-fh8Xd1/pbr-0.5.23/pbr/util.py", line 480, in wrap_commands

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 772, in get_command_list

klass = self.get_command_class(cmd)

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 366, in get_command_class

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 815, in get_command_class

__import__ (module_name)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/check.py", line 13, in <module>

from docutils.utils import Reporter

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils/utils/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>

from docutils.io import FileOutput

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils/io.py", line 18, in <module>

from docutils.utils.error_reporting import locale_encoding, ErrorString, ErrorOutput

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils/utils/error_reporting.py", line 47, in <module>

locale_encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 511, in getdefaultlocale

return _parse_localename(localename)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 443, in _parse_localename

raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename

ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in  /private/var/folders/hl/n7326xr91ls3z8c3s08_dv4r0000gn/T/pip_build_rafagomes/virtualenvwrapper
Storing complete log in /Users/user/.pip/pip.log
```

Can anyone help me? Nothing on Google works

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem you need to fix your "local" variables in your .bashrc or .profile file.

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

More information [here](http://patrick.arminio.info/blog/2012/02/fix-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf8/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll se if works...right now I am at work, this problem happens in my personal computer

Comment: Worked, sorry about delay.